# Can't start Android Studio under Ubuntu 64 bit 13.04

Tags: java, android, ide, intellij-idea

I have downloaded this early preview, I know that it's not stable and everything but I see no one complaining on the most populated forums and my copy of Android Studio doesn't even starts.

I have tried with both JDK 1.6 and 1.7 from Oracle in the PATH but it always fails ( i have JAVA_HOME set too )

[image]

and this alert shows up 3 times and the startup just freezes, [this is the complete](http://pastebin.com/Lb2aqZ4t) output of about the failed start.

there is also 0 real practical documentation for this SDK, so I don't even any idea what the requirements for this suite are.

*Strange fact*: there is this file `Install-Linux-tar.txt` in the root of the android studio folder that suggest to run this `./android studio.sh` command from the `bin` sub-directory but there is no `./android` in that subdir and the instructions make no sense at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that java is installed in /user/java and not another directory.

I had same issue and simply moving Java directory fixed this issue

(I found a Google answer in a few seconds..)

For the second remark, that's totally true: forget.`/android studio.h` and simply use `./studio.h`

[image]

Comment: can you please give the full path for java ? it should be `/user/java/bin/java` ?

Comment: /usr/jav... I added screenshot just in case ;-)

Comment: thanks I forgot to ask if you are under a 32 bit or a 64 bit JVM